# Plot showing up as empty plot

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I am trying to populate my 2-d scatter-plot. I have a 3-d scatter-plot using the same data, so I know the data works.

I have tried loading my own data manually with dummy numbers, but the plot still does not show. So I assume it is an issue with my formatting.

```py
@app.callback(
    Output("scat", "figure"),
    [Input("select-xaxis", "value"),
     Input("select-yaxis", "value"),
     Input("select-zaxis", "value"),
     Input("select-species", "value"),
     Input('studies', 'value'),
     Input('foams', 'value'),
     Input('surfactants', 'value'),
     Input('additives', 'value'),
     Input('lp', 'value')],
)
def update_scat(selected_x, selected_y, selected_z, selected_species, st, fo, sur, add, lp):
    c = dv[dv['Study'].isin(st)]
    le = c[c['Foam'].isin(fo)]
    an = le[le['Surfactant'].isin(sur)]
    ed = an[an['Additive'].isin(add)]
    cleaned = ed[ed['LiquidPhase'].isin(lp)]

    fig = [go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
                            x=cleaned[selected_x].to_numpy(),
                            y=cleaned[selected_y].to_numpy(),
                            mode = 'markers',
                            marker = {
                                "size":20,
                                "color":cleaned[selected_species],
                            },
                            text="Study: " + cleaned.Study + "<br />Foam: " + cleaned.Foam + "<br />Surfactant: " + cleaned.Surfactant + "<br />Additive: " + cleaned.Additive + "<br />Liquid Phase: " + cleaned.LiquidPhase,))]

    return  {"data": fig,
            "layout": go.Layout(
                paper_bgcolor="#202020",
                height=938,
                xaxis={"title": f"{selected_x.title()}"}, 
                yaxis={"title": f"{selected_y.title()}"}, )
            }
```

Below is an example of my code with dummy numbers, it does not give an error, but it just does not display anything but a blank graph. Also, when I return fig.show() in the above statement, I get an error because of my returning format, but it displays the correct graph in another tab. I do not understand why it does not load in my website though.

```py
def update_scat(selected_x, selected_y, selected_z, selected_species, st, fo, sur, add, lp):
    c = dv[dv['Study'].isin(st)]
    le = c[c['Foam'].isin(fo)]
    an = le[le['Surfactant'].isin(sur)]
    ed = an[an['Additive'].isin(add)]
    cleaned = ed[ed['LiquidPhase'].isin(lp)]

    fig = [go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(
                            x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                            y=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
                            mode = 'markers',
                            marker = {
                                "size":20,
                                "color":cleaned[selected_species],
                            },
                            text="Study: " + cleaned.Study + "<br />Foam: " + cleaned.Foam + "<br />Surfactant: " + cleaned.Surfactant + "<br />Additive: " + cleaned.Additive + "<br />Liquid Phase: " + cleaned.LiquidPhase,))]

    return  {"data": fig,
            "layout": go.Layout(
                paper_bgcolor="#202020",
                xaxis={"title": f"{selected_x.title()}"}, 
                yaxis={"title": f"{selected_y.title()}"}, )
            }
```

Comment: If your error is reproducible using dummy numbers, please provide an example using those dummy numbers so that we have a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with.

Comment: Are you able to produce *any* plotly figure using another approch?

Comment: I adjusted my code above by adding a section using dummy numbers. I also explained another piece of the puzzle

Comment: got it working, just started from scratch :)